# PayPal SOAP API Error 13606 When trying to call Refund API method with Payer ID and amount

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

When I try to call RefundTransaction API method usiong PayerID i get Error "13606 Feature Not Enabled. You are not enabled for this feature.".

What it does mean? Is there a way to enable it?

To reproduce you can go to https://devtools-paypal.com/apiexplorer/PayPalAPIs and try to execute RefundTransaction method with PayerID and Amount filled in.

Answer (score 3):

Direct from PayPal Support:

> TransactionID and PayerID are marked "conditional", but you couldn't set blank.
>
> For example, A buyer purchased several items in different period , but if you call RefundTransaciton API only set PayerID,
>   PayPal couldn't judge in which transaction to refund, and also could not refund the amount about all of these items.
>
> PayPal is not allowed this case happen.
>
> So at least you have to set the transaction ID while calling the refund API.

So the solution is to **always specify TransactionID**.

Yes, their own [API Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/RefundTransaction_API_Operation_SOAP/) says:
"Either the transaction ID **or** the payer ID must be specified."
But apparently this is not the case.

If you don't log `subscr_payment` IPN calls, you can look up `TransactionID` from a `PayerID` by using the [`TransactionSearch`](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_SOAP/) API request. Put your `PayerID` in the `ProfileID` search field.